# arrange() putting capital letters first

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I usually use the `arrange()` function from `dplyr` to sort datasets, but it behaved in a way that I couldn't understand. Took me a little while to get to the bottom of this. I've fixed my code and used `order()` to do the same thing, but now I'm curious. I have used `arrange()` without thinking twice for ages, and I wonder why this seems to be the default behavior. It looks like it fails to sort alphabetically when capital letters are involved--as in, it believes capital letters should come prior to lowercase letters, even if the latter precede them in the alphabet. Am I missing something?

This is not always a problem, but it did become one for me when I used `tapply()` immediately after arranging via `arrange()`, assuming that the data would be sorted in the same way that `tapply()` sorts when running. Here's an example of `arrange()` putting "USSR" before "Uganda" and the "Ukraine", whereas `order()` (correctly, I think!) puts it last.

```
library(dplyr)
countries<-c("USSR","Uganda","Ukraine")
tmp<-data.frame(countries,stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp %>% arrange(countries) #orders it one way
tmp[order(tmp$countries),] #orders it another way
sort(tmp$countries) #sort agrees with order
```

I looked around to see whether others had encountered this same problem, and couldn't see anything. Forgive me if this has been discussed previously.

Comment: I wonder if this bit from ?arrange is relevant: "Note that for local data frames, the ordering is done in C++ code which does not have access to the local specific ordering usually done in R. This means that strings are ordered as if in the C locale."

Comment: See also the discussion on the `?Comparison` help page, specifically the paragraph describing essentially how `order()` works that begins "Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use."

Comment: Thanks. That is annoying! But revealing..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does R 3.6.0 return FALSE when evaluating the expression ("Dogs" < "cats")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485774/why-does-r-3-6-0-return-false-when-evaluating-the-expression-dogs-cats)

Comment: This question is newer, but has a much more detailed answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the comment from @MrFlick is correct. If I do

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE","C")
```

then

```
tmp[order(tmp$countries),]
```

matches the result from `arrange()`

Comment: But! There doesn't seem to be a way to easily change the locale for dplyr, at least on a windows box.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentaton](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) it requires a definition of a [locale](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr-locale.html). In this case the issue would be resolved adding `.locale="en"` :

```
tmp %>% arrange(countries, .locale="en")
```